# add_image_size not working with the_post_thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

Code in my funcitons.php

```
function custom_thumbs() {
    add_image_size( 'cover-size', 1600, 450, true ); 
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_thumbs' );
```

Usage:

`echo the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'cover-size');`

but this is the result:

```
<img width="3648" height="2736" src="http://localhost/sonru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/DSC04656.jpg" class="attachment-9 size-9 wp-post-image" alt="DSC04656" cover-size="" srcset="http://localhost/sonru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/DSC04656-300x225.jpg 300w, http://localhost/sonru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/DSC04656-600x450.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 3648px) 100vw, 3648px">
```

What Am I missing here?

-Edit-

I'm already regenerating thumbnails using the `regenerate thunbnails` plugin

Comment: As a side-note, your comment next to `add_image_size` suggests there would be an unlimited height which is not the case as you've specified a *max-height* of 450 ( and anything else to be cropped ). If you truly want to replicate an "unlimited height" you would need to put in a extremely large number such as `999999`

Comment: @Howdy_McGee copy and past has a danger.... edited ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to regenerate your images. There are plugins to accomplish this or re-upload your image and see if the size doesn't take affect. It won't happen automatically to existing files.

First, check your uploads directory to see if the files exists that way you know they are being generated. Then try another function to output the results.

What do you end up with when you use:

```
$attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ); 
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'cover-size' ); 
$img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, 'cover-size' );
```

Also if may be handy to output your meta data for that attachment - specifically to see the `size` information:

```
print_r ( wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id) );
```

The above `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset` requires WordPress 4.4 and you can find more information about [Responsive Images in WordPress 4.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/).

Assuming the files exist:

- [the_post_thumbnail](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) `( $size, $attr )`
- [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) `( int|WP_Post $post = null, string|array $size = 'post-thumbnail', string|array $attr = '' )`

Are you in a Loop or outside of it?

If you're inside try `the_post_thumbnail ('cover-size');`

otherwise `echo get_the_post_thumbnail ($post,'cover-size');`

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm already using regenerte thumbnails plugin

Comment: Yes, actually `DSC04656-1600x450.jpg` exists...

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_image_url` works, but `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset` returns empty... ( If you edit the quesiton i'll acept it)

Comment: You are just copying info from my answer now and I don't appreciate it. Your edits are invalid

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function:

- [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) does not accept the post ID as value, but the image size.
- [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) is what you need and maybe trying to use. The first parameter accept the post ID and the second parameter accepts the image size to use as in your question

### SOLUTION

Swap `the_post_thumbnail()` with `get_the_post_thumbnail()`

### EDIT

Just a note, make sure that you add your new image size after you have added support for thumbnails. Also, you would want to add a new post thumbnail size with [`set_post_thumbnail_size()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size)

Comment: See my edit in **EDIT** and don't forget to regenerate thumbnails